# How to make holes in several plains at once

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

Image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

I can't figure out how I can make holes in that pages where each ring is attached there in several pages beside it like 15-20. How can I cut holes there?

Comment: Do you need it to be low poly?

Comment: @LukeD no i m trying to making realastic render

Comment: Instead of many holes, do just one section with one hole, and use an array modifier to complete the page, for the rings you can also use an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Final:

[image: Final]

Simplest way with quad topology would be to cut holes in Subdivided Plane and add Subdivision Surface modifier.

### Steps:

[image: steps]

1. Create a **Plane**.
2. Go to **Edit Mode** and **Subdivide** it twice. First time with **10 cuts**, second one with **1**. You can go further if you need different hole placement.
3. Select faces where you want your holes and delete them.
4. Remove unnecessary faces to trim page as you want.
5. Select outer edge of the mesh and add to it **Mean Crease > 1**. This will ensure that corners stay sharp after **Subdivision Surface** modifier will be added.
6. Add **Subdivision Surface** modifier. I've set it to **2**.

### Final touches:

[image: fine_tune]

If you want smaller holes you can select **Edge Loop** around them in **Edge Select** mode, switch to **Pivot Center > Individual Origins**, then **Extrude** and **Scale** them down.